# How to use xpath xpression for multiple condtions to check if data is present or not in wso2 ESB?

Tags: xpath, wso2, wso2-esb

For a single condition I know the empty check is done using something like the following:

```
boolean(get-property('ID'))
```

What if I need this done for multiple properties (id and name for example)?

I tried the following and it did not work:

```
<filter source="boolean(get-property('ID')) and boolean(get-property('Name'))"
                                        regex="true">
```

Comment: Never tell us something didn't work. Always tell us how it failed.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
<filter xpath="boolean(get-property('ID')) and boolean(get-property('Name'))">
```